# How can I wire this square Pot?

Tags: led, components, potentiometer, speakers

[image: square potentiometer]How can I wire this 6 pin pot to control a speaker and LED. I know how to wire up normal circular potentiometers, and I feel like this pot may be broken, but how can I tell?

Answer (score 7):

That's a multi-section variable and semi-fixed (trimmer) capacitor out of a radio.

Here is pretty good photo of a similar vintage part (from [here](https://www.radiodaze.com/4-section-am-fm-transistor-style-variable-capacitors-new-old-stock-box-of-50/)):

[image]

[image]

Typically one variable section would be  used for the AM band and one section for the FM band.

You can't practically use  it directly to control an LED or speaker volume, but you might be able to use it as an input to an MCU by making an oscillator with it and counting the frequency.

Comment: thanks for the info

Answer (score 4):

It's not a potentiometer but a ganged 4 section variable capacitor (generally referred to as a 'Polyvaricon' or 'PVC Gang Condenser / Capacitor'), with each capacitor having a trimmer capacitor in parallel.

[image]

Its intended for use in AM / FM superheterodyne receivers for tuning the antenna and oscillator circuits. The AM sections would be 365 pF each and the FM ones 20 pf.

Comment: thanks for the info

Comment: Anytime, hassan naqvi!